# 4-layer perceptron neural network classifying the MNIST digit dataset not working correctly

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, perceptron

I just started getting into machine learning with little coding background and wanted to create a simple perceptron neural network that learns to classify the MNIST digit dataset without the use of machine learning libraries. Under output_data I have put the first and last 80 print statements my program outputs. It seems my program is learning to minimize the cost function, but it gets stuck guessing the same digit over and over again. I have messed with the learning rate and batch sizes but they don't seem to improve anything. If someone could lead me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thanks

## mnist_recognition

This is a 4-layer neural network that classifies handwritten digits in the mnist data set.
Using only pure python and numpy, this program calculates the gradient descent of the cost function 
(∑(actual - target)^2) with respect to the weights, and changes the weights accordingly.
After each iteration, the program prints the digit of the training data, the program's guess 
and the cost associated with that iteration.


Importing MNIST training data

```
with np.load('mnist.npz') as data:
    training_images = data['training_images']
    training_labels = data['training_labels']
```

Setting up the neural network and defining sigmoid function 
self.mtrx holds the neurons in each level 
self.weight, bias, grad hold weight, bias and gradient values between level L and L - 1

```
class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, rows, columns=0):
        self.mtrx = np.zeros((rows, 1))
        self.weight = np.random.random((rows, columns)) / columns ** .5
        self.bias = np.random.random((rows, 1)) * -1.0
        self.grad = np.zeros((rows, columns))

    def sigmoid(self):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-self.mtrx))

    def sigmoid_derivative(self):
        return self.sigmoid() * (1.0 - self.sigmoid())
```

Initializing neural network levels

```
lvl_input = NeuralNetwork(784)
lvl_one = NeuralNetwork(200, 784)
lvl_two = NeuralNetwork(200, 200)
lvl_output = NeuralNetwork(10, 200)
```

Forward and backward propagation functions

```
def forward_prop():
    lvl_one.mtrx = lvl_one.weight.dot(lvl_input.mtrx) + lvl_one.bias
    lvl_two.mtrx = lvl_two.weight.dot(lvl_one.sigmoid()) + lvl_two.bias
    lvl_output.mtrx = lvl_output.weight.dot(lvl_two.sigmoid()) + lvl_output.bias


def back_prop(actual):
    val = np.zeros((10, 1))
    val[actual] = 1

    delta_3 = (lvl_output.sigmoid() - val) * lvl_output.sigmoid_derivative()
    delta_2 = np.dot(lvl_output.weight.transpose(), delta_3) * lvl_two.sigmoid_derivative()
    delta_1 = np.dot(lvl_two.weight.transpose(), delta_2) * lvl_one.sigmoid_derivative()

    lvl_output.grad = lvl_two.sigmoid().transpose() * delta_3
    lvl_two.grad = lvl_one.sigmoid().transpose() * delta_2
    lvl_one.grad = lvl_input.sigmoid().transpose() * delta_1
```

Storing mnist data into np.array

```
def make_image(c): 
    lvl_input.mtrx = training_images[c]
```

Evaluating cost function

```
def cost(actual):
    val = np.zeros((10, 1))
    val[actual] = 1
    cost_val = (lvl_output.sigmoid() - val) ** 2
    return np.sum(cost_val)
```

Subtraction gradients from weights and initializing learning rate

```
learning_rate = .01

def update():
    lvl_output.weight -= learning_rate * lvl_output.grad
    lvl_two.weight -= learning_rate * lvl_two.grad
    lvl_one.weight -= learning_rate * lvl_one.grad
```

Training neural network 
iter_1 equals number of batches 
iter_2 equals number of iterations in one batch

```
iter_1 = 50
iter_2 = 100

for batch_num in range(iter_1):
    update()
    for batches in range(iter_2):
        make_image(counter)
        num = np.argmax(training_labels[counter])
        counter += 1
        forward_prop()
        back_prop(num)
        print("actual: ", num, "     guess: ", np.argmax(lvl_output.mtrx), "     cost", cost(num))
```

## output_data

```
FIRST 80 ITERATIONS:

actual:  5      guess:  3      cost 8.967940654671088
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.96727511953835
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.966336311471029
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.964614419297058
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.969134701891605
actual:  2      guess:  3      cost 8.967053265932318
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.964824848818395
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.966473334609903
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.960864501044062
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.966927097539942
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.96602960141387
actual:  5      guess:  3      cost 8.96457467709148
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.966463452568336
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.967170896271007
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.961504554251428
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.970226265002914
actual:  2      guess:  3      cost 8.966534186296752
actual:  8      guess:  3      cost 8.96806492904598
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.963241663267867
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.967891094208154
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.968165257872185
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.967495671691166
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.967110016262358
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.964392716554022
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.965993742374005
actual:  2      guess:  3      cost 8.967551426336762
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.963912501397779
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.966729854711515
actual:  2      guess:  3      cost 8.967571805901548
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.968031754047926
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.965675580057647
actual:  8      guess:  3      cost 8.968461428875388
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.965166939019545
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.968763204750987
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.967540507250032
actual:  5      guess:  3      cost 8.965545688959857
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.967425028943891
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.967566971035732
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.969754175784066
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.96702539598315
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.96299163011006
actual:  8      guess:  3      cost 8.968175816089042
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.966425056294776
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.96796817338183
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.963755408168
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.96926567423336
actual:  8      guess:  3      cost 8.967543729824387
actual:  5      guess:  3      cost 8.967286499095575
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.9677253773608
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.966335253428326
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.962829459684784
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.966443407799728
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.969485491531145
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.964159055804105
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.968054200103934
actual:  8      guess:  3      cost 8.96719386034473
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.966374739396157
actual:  9      guess:  3      cost 8.9673694447568
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.966879451409914
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.963085409100401
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.96659585831308
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.964656458614465
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.965997487130116
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.966455019673488
actual:  4      guess:  3      cost 8.966295463866858
actual:  5      guess:  3      cost 8.964316168401316
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.965707649845031
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.962325088384468
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.965286965834165
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.966383201903987
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.964628836235496
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.968386161233427
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.959224945536565
actual:  6      guess:  3      cost 8.965609436078736
actual:  3      guess:  3      cost 8.964347604784498
actual:  0      guess:  3      cost 8.96611237840382
actual:  2      guess:  3      cost 8.965381094981499
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.963120677127996
actual:  1      guess:  3      cost 8.96405639510175
actual:  7      guess:  3      cost 8.968933638290096

LAST 80 ITERATIONS:

actual:  5      guess:  7      cost 1.1211637067627063
actual:  6      guess:  7      cost 1.0552531331006683
actual:  6      guess:  7      cost 1.0554754137400155
actual:  1      guess:  7      cost 1.1111335796511572
actual:  7      guess:  7      cost 0.39288606314850105
actual:  0      guess:  7      cost 0.9725346172858359
actual:  8      guess:  7      cost 1.1328622780173858
actual:  7      guess:  7      cost 0.3948858827858138
actual:  9      guess:  7      cost 1.1062621497616252
actual:  6      guess:  7      cost 1.0553258043668636
actual:  0      guess:  7      cost 0.9722536736320497
actual:  9      guess:  7      cost 1.104398056849663
actual:  1      guess:  7      cost 1.1107715879340798
actual:  6      guess:  7      cost 1.0548862811967128
actual:  2      guess:  7      cost 1.0591572140435124
actual:  9      guess:  7      cost 1.1061966300353054
actual:  3      guess:  7      cost 1.0898127633513548
actual:  2      guess:  7      cost 1.060007348683317
actual:  4      guess:  7      cost 1.0866881038452423
actual:  5      guess:  7      cost 1.121417891094558
actual:  5      guess:  7      cost 1.120467850157213
actual:  1      guess:  7      cost 1.108298490272241
actual:  6      guess:  7      cost 1.0553087806403634
actual:  1      guess:  7      cost 1.110088687169048
actual:  7      guess:  7      cost 0.39320440442417653
actual:  7      guess:  7      cost 0.393599379050548
actual:  8      guess:  7      cost 1.132814048747761
actual:  5      guess:  7      cost 1.121939678599679
actual:  9      guess:  7      cost 1.106025451446512
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9622564124884784
actual:  0      guess:  0      cost 0.8593530649130317
actual:  4      guess:  0      cost 0.9393396290138495
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9622940421810162
actual:  4      guess:  0      cost 0.9404822496691384
actual:  2      guess:  0      cost 0.9178125638868906
actual:  3      guess:  0      cost 0.9426691285338776
actual:  3      guess:  0      cost 0.942690753734257
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9623297861049644
actual:  4      guess:  0      cost 0.940371478405245
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9623031268176
actual:  5      guess:  0      cost 0.9712347696568674
actual:  0      guess:  0      cost 0.8590451041238242
actual:  6      guess:  0      cost 0.9144392962122468
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8587038959856634
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8595722910216409
actual:  3      guess:  0      cost 0.9426103963458455
actual:  8      guess:  0      cost 0.9818405405702578
actual:  9      guess:  0      cost 0.8595962707758777
actual:  5      guess:  0      cost 0.9714964202087537
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9624568499960074
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9618997440804723
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9616207680615205
actual:  9      guess:  0      cost 0.8592443630955677
actual:  5      guess:  0      cost 0.9713378210566505
actual:  9      guess:  0      cost 0.8594114362413322
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9618546105579062
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8588493542347546
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9618718521886025
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9617515805652713
actual:  6      guess:  0      cost 0.9136159964857046
actual:  0      guess:  0      cost 0.8592350961109494
actual:  8      guess:  0      cost 0.9818162514673088
actual:  9      guess:  0      cost 0.8595943721384651
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8594020275011919
actual:  0      guess:  0      cost 0.8594831625021346
actual:  2      guess:  0      cost 0.9166105269490908
actual:  5      guess:  0      cost 0.9715520240455258
actual:  3      guess:  0      cost 0.9426616801200285
actual:  9      guess:  0      cost 0.859581449204677
actual:  6      guess:  0      cost 0.9142265327401935
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8588630292850988
actual:  8      guess:  0      cost 0.981801914298837
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9618275889195599
actual:  0      guess:  0      cost 0.8587978160230371
actual:  7      guess:  0      cost 0.8591755187382748
actual:  3      guess:  0      cost 0.9427927022073027
actual:  2      guess:  0      cost 0.9175924937090146
actual:  1      guess:  0      cost 0.9608604565831466
actual:  2      guess:  0      cost 0.9171708777221477
--- 3.403271198272705 seconds ---
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Noah. For better of worse, there are some rules here, one of them is that your code must be inlined in the question. If the code is large, then reduce it to the a small problem area.

Comment: [troll mode] looks like your network has learned something... at first it guessed 3 all the time, towards the end, 7 and finally 0, which is probably a statistically better overall/random guess. And the cost is down, so, yay! Of course, your network failed to learn the inner structure of the problem...

Comment: Depending on the problem and your network and hyper-parameters, `50*100` iterations may be simply soo few. Try a few orders of magnitude more first; Then try tuning hyper-parameters :)

Comment: Also, just in case, please ensure that your training data is in random order, e.g. `193...715..824` and not `111...222...999`

Comment: @DimaTisnek I finally got it working with an error of about 7%. It ended up being a combination of the learning rate and batch size. The batch size that worked best was one, oddly enough. And this was with 50,000 different training data. Do you know why this would be? I thought stochastic gradient descent was less efficient.

Comment: You'd need to ask a professor about that.